# A question about punctiform point sets

Tags: general-topology

Let E be a finite dimensional Euclidean space whose dimension is at least two and let P be a punctiform subset of E. Is the complement of P in E always connected and locally connected? I know that the answer is "yes", if P is totally imperfect, but I am not clear what happens when P is only punctiform-especially about the "locally connected" part.

Comment: What does "punctiform" mean? I've never seen this term before. EDIT: I found https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Perfect_compactification, which defines "punctiform" as "containing no compact connected subset with more than one point"; is that correct?

Comment: Yes. That is correct

Comment: You ask some fairly deep questions, and it's difficult to tell what you already know. Do you know if the answer is yes for the plane? (if so, could you explain). Also what is totally imperfect? This is not a common term.

Comment: @Forever Mozart: I have found a reference to a theorem in the literature which states that P is connected whenever the dimension of E is greater  than 1. But I am still in the dark about whether P is locally connected, even when E is the Euclidean plane,. A subset S of E is called "totally imperfect" if S is uncountable and contains no perfect subset. Some of the questions I am asking may have been of more interest to topologists early in the last century. That could be why some of the terms I am using don't seem too familiar. .

Comment: @GarabedGulbenkian I feel like it should be locally connected, because the euclidean balls are homeomorphic to the entire $E$, and you are only removing a punctiform set from them.

Comment: @Forever Mozart:  That is a very clever observation. A punctiform subset P should not be able to disconnect the interior B of a Euclidean ball, since there is a theorem stating that P cannot disconnect E, and B is a homeomorphic image of E. ....Incidentally, my definition of "totally imperfect" was not quite correct. S should have the cardinal number of the continuum-and not merely be uncountable. Otherwise the notion is trivial.